# Bluetooth not working at all after I made some changes to pair with PS3 joystick

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, joystick

I have a "media stuff" computer connected to a TV that I use to play films, music and for gaming.

Lately I wanted to use either or both my Wii and PS3 joysticks via the bluetooth provided by the motherboard. At first my PC seemed to be able to detect the PS3 joysticks but not pair them. I was even able to pair a PS3 joystick and see the various actions I triggered, but the device would become unpaired when I closed the program.

I tried various ideas from how-tos here and there. The system finally ended up with the Bluetooth not able to work properly...

Now when I start a new session the Bluetooth icon near the hour is not showing. I can start the Bluetooth app but no devices are detected. I may have messed with drivers while following a `modprobe` instruction in the howtos.

`sudo lspci | grep -i blue` is not showing anything. Neither is `lsusb`

The motherboard is a GIGABYTE GA-Z87N-WIFI and bluetooth once worked.
I use Ubuntu 16.04.

How can I solve this?

A bit of output here:

```
louis@cinema-wifi:~$ sudo dmesg | grep Blue
[   16.088420] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   16.088438] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.088441] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.088444] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.088448] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   18.231336] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[   26.227321] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
[   28.231323] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[   36.227354] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
[   36.648754] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   36.648756] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   36.648760] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 8741.765627] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[ 8749.761485] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
[ 8811.536379] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[ 8819.532238] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
[ 8821.536199] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c03 tx timeout
[ 8829.532066] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
louis@cinema-wifi:~$ sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; sudo lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 041e:323d Creative Technology, Ltd
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:0116 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd KU-2971/KU-0325 Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I just updated the question as requested, thanks

Comment: Try to boot with another kernel using grub. It looks something is broken in the kernel. But I am using this adapter and see no problems.

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Comment: once I boot with the other kernel (I will take a previous version), can you direct me to some reliable instructions on how to remove the deffective kernel and add it back from repository, I want to make it worse...

Comment: First try if BT works on a previous kernel. I have the latest 4.10 and BT works with the same hardware.

Comment: The kernel (4.4.0-72-generic) itself loaded correctly but without the BT icon in the top right.
corner. So I started Buetooth by clicking on it from the «?start? menu». It returned the error message that it could not connect to Bluez. I made no change and rebooted to the previous kernel (4.4.14-040414-generic).

Comment: Should I reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: Is there any other way to get help for this as nobody answer?

Comment: Run `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04` and reboot. This will install the 4.10 kernel.

Comment: I did that but bluethoot is not startint with ubuntu, when I start the bluetooth manager manually, it gives an error message: connection to bluez failed. bluez deamon is not active, bluman-manager cant continue. this probably means that no bluetooth adapter was detected or that the bluetooth daemon did not start.

Any idea what I can do from here?

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu, bluetooth did not come back :(

Comment: Is there a way to make Ubuntu rescan for hardware devices to add the correct modules in the kernel?

Comment: The module is there, but it can't load firmware. Try `sudo modprobe -r btusb && sudo modprobe btusb`.

Comment: the command itself dont give any output
then trying Bluez manager, it says no adapter found

Comment: Report a bug. Maybe a hardware problem. This adapter works for me.

Comment: Is there a way to know what Ubutun kernel used iwlwifi-firmware-7260-16.ucode (-17 is the current)?

I will try an older kernel first as it was working previously...

Answer (score 10):

TL;DR: Turn off, remove power supply, get a coffee and reboot.

I had a similar problem where my GF plugged her phone into the USB cable that I have plugged into my PC for data transfers. All of the sudden my BT headset stopped working and all bluetooth activity was stopped. I searched through the kernel log and found similar logs as you

```
Mar 15 16:14:54 pascalwhoop vmunix: [  110.560078] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.118935] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.118943] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.118944] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.118945] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.118947] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148196] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148197] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148198] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148209] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148210] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148210] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148227] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148235] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148235] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148236] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   10.148236] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   12.160110] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c03 tx timeout
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.971314] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.971316] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.971318] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Mar 15 19:37:20 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   20.192100] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
```

Then I found [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171357) post which told me to just *not reboot but turn off, disconnect power, let the condensators clear out and then reconnect*. Did that, and boom:

```
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.506983] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.506992] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.506994] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.506995] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.506998] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513817] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513818] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513818] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513825] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513825] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513825] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513838] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513843] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513844] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513844] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.513844] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.558591] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370710018002030d00
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.559913] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   13.692579] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   18.074597] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   18.074598] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   18.074600] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   24.987387] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   24.987396] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Mar 15 20:00:46 pascalwhoop vmunix: [   24.987402] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

I am running a

```
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

device to be Hackintosh compatible but actually switched to Debian all the way.

Comment: Surprisingly worked for me.

Comment: who would imagine.

Comment: After a lot of debugging and headaches I came across this answer and it worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/q/1182850/305791

Comment: "get a coffee" is quite misleading, you can even "get a tea", it worked in my case :D

Comment: (In my idiolect at least, "remove power supply" would mean opening the case and performing surgery.)  Simply telling the computer to turn itself off, then waiting perhaps half a minute, then powering it back on worked for me, thanks, where a software-initiated reboot did not.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same issue.
Then, I did kernel update and old kernel grub boot and on...everything. all didn't work.

But pascalwhoop answer is perfectly working.

Just turn off by

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

and unplug all the cable like power, Monitor HDMI, USB, UTP Cat5.e everything.
And Plug it and boot your system.

And it works now fantastically.

I made answer here due to comment is not allowed with lack of SOF reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after installing **xpadneo** to get my **xbox one controller** to work over bluetooth on Ubuntu. It worked gret for 2 days and the controller stopped appearing.

Multiple restarts and searching for possible driver issues, amounted to nothing. Evening switching it off and on again did nothing.

Finally, unplugging it for and then starting up again did the trick.