# Bluetooth problem - continuous turn on/off every 2~3 seconds?

Tags: bluetooth

Ubuntu Version : 18.04
Kernel : 4.15.0-45-generic

I don't know the reason but suddenly bluetooth doesn't work in my ubuntu machine.
As you see the syslog, it's repeating unlimtedely. It's happening every 1~2 seconds.
It's crazy now.

It worked fine last week. but today I realized that it has problem now.

Can anyone help?

```
179898 Feb 18 23:08:17 RibornServer systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
179899 Feb 18 23:08:17 RibornServer upowerd[2029]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1
179900 Feb 18 23:08:17 RibornServer upowerd[2029]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0
179901 Feb 18 23:08:17 RibornServer upowerd[2029]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14
179902 Feb 18 23:08:19 RibornServer kernel: [ 2549.359309] usb 1-14: USB disconnect, device number 121
179903 Feb 18 23:08:19 RibornServer kernel: [ 2549.657249] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
179904 Feb 18 23:08:27 RibornServer systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
179905 Feb 18 23:08:27 RibornServer kernel: [ 2557.689245] Bluetooth: hci0 sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
179906 Feb 18 23:08:27 RibornServer upowerd[2029]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.1
179907 Feb 18 23:08:27 RibornServer systemd[1]: bluetooth.target: Unit not needed anymore. Stopping.
179908 Feb 18 23:08:27 RibornServer systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth.
179909 Feb 18 23:08:27 RibornServer upowerd[2029]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14/1-14:1.0
179910 Feb 18 23:08:27 RibornServer upowerd[2029]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-14
179911 Feb 18 23:08:27 RibornServer systemd-rfkill[12168]: Failed to open device rfkill208: No such device
179912 Feb 18 23:08:27 RibornServer systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
179913 Feb 18 23:08:28 RibornServer kernel: [ 2557.961259] usb 1-14: new full-speed USB device number 122 using xhci_hcd
179914 Feb 18 23:08:28 RibornServer kernel: [ 2558.089287] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
179915 Feb 18 23:08:28 RibornServer kernel: [ 2558.325273] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
179916 Feb 18 23:08:28 RibornServer kernel: [ 2558.561251] usb 1-14: new full-speed USB device number 123 using xhci_hcd
179917 Feb 18 23:08:28 RibornServer kernel: [ 2558.689276] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
179918 Feb 18 23:08:29 RibornServer kernel: [ 2558.925279] usb 1-14: device descriptor read/64, error -71
179919 Feb 18 23:08:29 RibornServer kernel: [ 2559.033312] usb usb1-port14: attempt power cycle
179920 Feb 18 23:08:30 RibornServer kernel: [ 2559.893209] usb 1-14: new full-speed USB device number 124 using xhci_hcd
179921 Feb 18 23:08:30 RibornServer kernel: [ 2559.914756] usb 1-14: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0aa7
179922 Feb 18 23:08:30 RibornServer kernel: [ 2559.914761] usb 1-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue from similar question in
[Bluetooth not working at all after I made some changes to pair with PS3 joystick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952264/bluetooth-not-working-at-all-after-i-made-some-changes-to-pair-with-ps3-joystick/1119537#1119537)

- Just shutdown the system: `sudo shutdown -h now`
- unplug every connected Cable like power, HDMI, CAT5.E, even Keyboard & Mouse USB
- some seconds later, plug it again, and eventually it worked

I answer my question for whom experiences similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by updating my kernel to the latest (4.19 to 5.9), shutting down, unplugging all USB devices, rebooting, and plugging the devices in one by one.