# Ubuntu 19.10 Bluetooth on Intel AC 3168NGW Stopped working (WiFi still works)

Tags: bluetooth, intel, 19.10

Fresh install of Ubuntu 19.10, I didn't manually install any drivers, Wifi and Bluetooth both worked out of the box (Asrock Deskmini A300 with 3168 dual band M.2 wifi/bluetooth card).

The OS crashed today and then bluetooth hasn't worked since. **Wifi still works fine.** Bluetooth has seemingly crashed in the past, but a reboot or restarting it via the settings panel worked.

Now the bluetooth settings panel rotates between saying "No bluetooth found" to "bluetooth turned off" every few seconds. Trying to enable it does nothing.

The additional drivers panel in Software & Updates shows the "device is not working", however, it has always said this. This has not changed. Though I am unable to make any selection here as the buttons are greyed out.

Here's some of the syslog that shows when I try to enable bluetooth from the settings panel:

```
Oct 22 14:05:57 deskmini systemd[1]: Reached target Bluetooth.
Oct 22 14:05:59 deskmini kernel: [  521.124745] usb 1-3.1: USB disconnect, device number 52
Oct 22 14:05:59 deskmini kernel: [  521.146649] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c03 tx timeout
Oct 22 14:06:07 deskmini kernel: [  529.174629] Bluetooth: hci0: sending initial HCI reset command failed (-110)
Oct 22 14:06:07 deskmini systemd[1]: Stopped target Bluetooth
```

Drivers panel:

[image]

The Firmware files are present in /lib/firmware, I didn't manually install these: iwlwifi-3168-21.ucode, iwlwifi-3168-22.ucode, iwlwifi-3168-27.ucode, iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode

Any ideas how I can further debug this?

Comment: Same issue on Arch, 5.5.9. Mine also usually resolves with a full power-off (and also requires a full disconnect like your comment below, not just shutdown). Then comes back after a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in another thread: [Bluetooth not working at all after I made some changes to pair with PS3 joystick](https://askubuntu.com/a/1015282/305791)

Turn off the computer, unplug everything including power, give it a few minutes and then power back up. Bluetooth is back again. (I had tried powering off, and rebooting, but not disconnecting everything)

You can see in the screenshot that it is still acting strange in the Additional Drivers panel, but that Bluetooth devices are successfully connected:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same/similar issue on 19.10 since kernel updated to 5.3.0.24, but the solution doesn't seem to work.
Bluetooth doesn't turn on. In cli tried bluetoothctl but it just keeps responding No default device available. Seems the module is offline. Maybe kernel downgrade would help, but I'm traveling so can't risk my only computer on hand right now.